# Errno::ECONNREFUSED (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I created simple contact form from where my website's visitours could send us some questions directly from that form using ActionMailer.

I did everything like int this guide :
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

**My mailer code:**

```
class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'
  def welcome_email(mail)
    @mail = mail
    mail(to: @mail.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

**Mailer view:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to example.com, <%= @mail.name %></h1>
    <p>
      You have successfully signed up to example.com,
      your username is: <br/>
    </p>
    <p>
      To login to the site, just follow this link: 
    </p>
    <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then I created controller Mail, where on creating Mail would automaticaly send that mail.

My create action:

```
 def create
    @mail = Mail.new(params[:mail])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @mail.save
        # Tell the UserMailer to send a welcome Email after save
        Mailer.welcome_email(@mail).deliver

        format.html { redirect_to(@mail, notice: 'User was successfully created.') }
        format.json { render json: @mail, status: :created, location: @mail }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @mail.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```

**My log file :**

```
Sent mail to ekk (2128ms)
Date: Fri, 24 Jan 2014 10:29:49 +0200
From: notifications@example.com
To: ekk
Message-ID: <52e2247dd72a4_1c50126a9b047573@Edzuks-PC.mail>
Subject: Welcome to My Awesome Site
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2321ms

Errno::ECONNREFUSED (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)):
  app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:31:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:29:in `create'


  Rendered c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (21.0ms)
```

**Problem**

I setup all smtp settings and in log file I can see that message is created but still get this error :

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)):
```

I tried to change that e-mail address to actual one, but without success.
Can somebody tip me for anything?

Thanks!!

Comment: What does your .log file say?  Could you post that info as well?

Comment: ^ Can't debug an error without the actual error.

Comment: @ChrisBarthol I updated my answer. I see that log file says :(uninitialized constant Mail::TestMailer). SO I will look into. ;)

Comment: where are you referencing TestMailer? The log refers to this but I don't see it in any of the code you posted. Is the code where you set the smtp_settings correct

Comment: @RoyTheBoy Where I have to set these smtp_settings? In my guide I refferenced there was no mention to do anything else than this.

Comment: @ChrisBarthol Updated my answer again

Comment: @Edgars Rozenfelds, in the guide you referenced, towards the end. Section 6 Action Mailer Configuration. What mail server are you trying to use?